# Select element inside other matched set of elements in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have following selector:

```js
var slots = $('.clinic-branch-2.doctor-has-specialty-3').parent().siblings();
```

which gives me this result:

```
[div.col-xs-3.col-sm-3.col-md-2, div.col-xs-4.col-sm-4.col-md-4.slots-go-here, prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document]
```

What I need is to select `.slots-go-here` element. 
I tried to access it with `[1]` index, however it returns raw HTML. Later I need to call `.html(someHtmlString)` on my selection. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.siblings` can take a selector. [*see docs*](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

`$('.clinic-branch-2.doctor-has-specialty-3').parent().siblings('.slots-go-here');`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass selector to [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method

```js
var slots = $('.clinic-branch-2.doctor-has-specialty-3').parent().siblings('.slots-go-here');
slots.html('Do Something')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can add class selector to siblings():

```
var slots = $('.clinic-branch-2.doctor-has-specialty-3').parent().siblings('.slots-go-here');
```